# Angular: setting options of a mat-select are not shown but applied when the value is null

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a multi-select in Angular and want to set some initial values. See the following example: 
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-vn4fx2)

Template

```
<form [formGroup]="filterFormGroup">
  <mat-form-field color="accent">
    <mat-label>{{ 'Users' }}</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="users" multiple>
      <mat-option [value]="null">No User</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="user1">User 1</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="user2">User 2</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="user3">User 3</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  filterFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    users: [[]],
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(x => console.log('changes: ' + JSON.stringify(x)));

    const preselectedFilters = {
      users: [null, 'user1']
    };
    this.filterFormGroup.setValue(preselectedFilters);
  }
}
```

Please note that `null` is a valid option in my example and not some placeholder.
The values are correctly set but the "null-option" is not shown as selected... only the "user1"-option is shown.

Can anyone explain to me why it is not shown as selected and maybe even provide a solution to the problem?

Comment: <mat-option [value]="null">No User</mat-option>
in the abv line keep  [value]=" 'null' "

Comment: I opened stackblitz and I see four options including 'No user' and can select it... Don't get the problem

Comment: @AnilKumarReddyA No, I want the value `null`, not the string "null".

Comment: @KaterinaPavlenko The problem is, that is should be selected by default when opening the stackblitz. Edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: The only way to achieve this is to convert the `null` value you receive from your backed to some specific value (like `0` if you are working with integers, `some-weird-string` if you are working with strings, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing null to ''

```
<mat-option value="">No User</mat-option>
 users: ['','user1']
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing right now as a workaround (I actually use an empty guid '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' because the other users are also guids).
However, the problem with this approach is that I am forced to transform the `null` values received from a service with my empty guid (or the empty string like you suggested) in order to filter for the selected values.